# Ruby - "invalid option: --port" Error

Tags: ruby, netbeans

I am very new to Ruby. And I am trying to make an existing project run. 
I have setup the environment on Netbeans.

After solving few error, I am stuck at this error :
**invalid option: --port**

It does not specify in which file is the actual error.

Please help.

Comment: I assume you're working on a Rails project. In the terminal, what do you see if you cd into your project directory and type `rails server --port 3000`?

Comment: @TimMorgan: Does this work on windows ? However, I can see in Netbeans  the server port is 3000.

Comment: Should work on Windows, sure. Just use the Command Prompt.

Comment: @TimMorgan: It does not work on command prompt.

Comment: What do you see? If you type just "rails" what do you see?

Comment: @TimMorgan: Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Comment: OK, good. The rails command works. Now, what happens when you cd to your project directory and type "rails server --port 3000"? Paste output please.

Comment: @TimMorgan : It does not work and just prints the usage and help.

Comment: Rails is not detecting your app. You're either not in the app directory, or you haven't yet generated an app. Maybe you need to `rails new app_name`... that's all I got.

Comment: @TimMorgan: No it does not work.